# How to add delay to @Async method for every request in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I have a service class and DAO class. In DAO class I am performing operations in DB using hibernate and JPA. I want to add some delay on the @Async method in DAO class.

Before every async call, there should be some delay. How can I do it without adding any delay in the service class?

Note: I do not want to add delay in my SearchService.java

SearchService.java

```
public void updateService(List<Map<String,Object>> req) {
      for(Map<String,Object> requestMap : req) {
            searchDao.saveEntity(requestMap);
      }
}
```

SearchDAO.java

```
@Async
@Retryable(value = Throwable.class, maxAttempts = REATTEMPT)
public void saveEntity(Map<String,Object> requestMap){
    // perform DB operations. insert or update in DB
}
```

Comment: I have a question, what is the purpose of the delay? If you want each asynchronous saveEntity execution to be until the previous ends, you can modify the size of the queue.

Comment: So while performing operations, if multiple threads work on the same record simultaneously then it creates an SQL exception. So I wanted to put some delay for every call or maybe as you said maintaining a queue size will also work out.

Comment: That is nonsense. If you got problems with 0 delay, how do you thing the same delay of X will fix the issue? If you pospone execution for that time, you will have the exact same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Though the method you're trying to achieve your goal with is very arguable, this could be done using Spring Aspects:

```
@Aspect
@Component // make sure your @ComponentScan processes the package this class is placed at
public class DelayAsyncOperations {

    @Around("@annotation(async)")
    public Object delayAsync(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

once I have had a problem like yours, and I solved it modifying the thread pool size to 1,
will be useful to avoid duplicate inserts in the db

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor bean = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    bean.setCorePoolSize(1);
    bean.setMaxPoolSize(1);
    bean.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(Boolean.TRUE);
    return bean;
}
```